# Como extraer datos de un diccionario dentro de una lista de diccionarios python

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

tengo un problema, habia leido diccionarios simples pero no uno como este. tengo este diccionario:

```py
{
    "timestamp": "2022-01-10T17:53:17.139",
    "Seccion1": {
        "libros": 0,
        "cuadernos": 42,
        "boligrafos": 16,
        "borradores": 26
    },
    "Seccion2": {
        "libros": 142,
        "cuadernos": 243,
        "boligrafos": 9,
        "borradores": 92
    },
    "Seccion3": {
        "libros": 12,
        "cuadernos": 78,
        "boligrafos": 0,
        "borradores": 66
    }
}
```

pero yo quisiera crear uno nuevo con estos datos:

```py
{
    {
    "timestamp": "2022-01-10T17:53:17.139",
    "Escuela":"Seccion1",
    "libros": 0,
    "cuadernos": 42,
    "boligrafos": 16,
    "borradores": 26
    },
        {
    "timestamp": "2022-01-10T17:53:17.139",
    "Escuela":"Seccion2",
    "libros": 0,
    "cuadernos": 42,
    "boligrafos": 16,
    "borradores": 26
    },
        {
    "timestamp": "2022-01-10T17:53:17.139",
    "Escuela":"Seccion3",
    "libros": 0,
    "cuadernos": 42,
    "boligrafos": 16,
    "borradores": 26
    }
}
```

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Además lo segundo que muestras no es un diccionario válido en python

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que esperas. El segundo resultado intentará crear un conjunto de diccionarios, dando error por que los diccionarios no son hashable. De cualquier modo, dudo que lo que esperes es crear un conjunto...